# What is needed for a node/typescript dynamic import to work? "await import(node:fs/promises)"

Tags: node.js, typescript, esbuild

Per the below, I've tried a wide number of different configurations, platforms, targets, etc, too long to list here and read the specifications, but the following is a bit of a mystery, so I'm finally reaching out here.  I can't find a good resource on anyone describing what is exactly needed.

In my working typescript/node project, I use a lot of static imports which work fine:

```
import * as fs from "fs";
```

However, if I switch this to a dynamic import:

```
const fs = await import("node:fs/promises")
```

I get this runtime error:

```
Failed to resolve module specifier 'fs/promises'
```

Some (possibly) relevant Esbuild settings:

```
platform:node 
external: ["fs/promises", ....] 
format: cjs 
target:es2020
```

tsconfig settings:

```
target:ES2022
module:NodeNext
moduleResolution:NodeNext


Node version: v21.2.0
Npm version: 10.2.4
tsc Version 5.2.2
```

Overall, just trying to understand a little bit more about how node needs to be configured to really allow this dynamic resolution and why.

Comment: Why would you need to dynamically import a Node internal module?

Comment: Technically, I ran into this issue when importing another well-known and used package: Langchain.  Internally, *it* uses that syntax to dynamically import a node module, so it fails.  Like you, I found that strange, but I cannot change the internals of that package.   To try to narrow down the issue, I removed that package and to test it, just tried it myself directly.   I think it's odd to try to do this, but in theory it should be a valid thing to do.

Comment: If it matters, https://github.com/langchain-ai/langchainjs/blob/main/langchain/src/vectorstores/faiss.ts , line 161.   I understand perhaps loading this on-demand on principle, but in the end, that's what the module does.  When I import this package into my project, it eventually hits this line and my own code fails.

Comment: Okay, and what environment are you targetting? Where do you get that "Failed to resolve module specifier 'fs/promises'" error?

Comment: I think it's becoming a little more clear here.  This is part of plugin development for a platform, and the execution environment actually appears to be running inside Electron, so this is running within a *browser* ultimately.  And I think that's the problem, since to my understanding a browser environment can never interpret non-url import() statements like import("node:ANYTHING").     Thus, I think due to the internal dynamic import of Langchain is doing (or any other package that does similar), I simply will not be able to use that package at all.  Let me know what you think.

Comment: Yeah, that's more clear now. Try slapping something like https://www.npmjs.com/package/esbuild-plugin-polyfill-node on it?

Comment: A great idea.  I'm using some of the same packages elsewhere in my own code, so there are some conflicts, but it seems like ultimately that kind of solution would be the only thing possible here.  Appreciate you taking the time and thanks.

Answer (score 2):

For posterity and future internet searchers, I thought I would add what seems to be the answer, or at least the reasoning why.

In my particular case, the typescript application is running within an elevated and custom Electron environment.  So, while it has elevated access to the file system and other node modules, it is still ultimately a browser in its behavior.  I have "platform=node" because it didn't make a difference in practice, but really, it should be "platform=browser".

When using import("node:WHATEVER") within a browser environment, the browser cannot interpret this.  It expects typically a url or similar.  So, in my case, it is perfectly fine to have a static import which gets bundled in, but a dynamic reference ultimately fails at runtime.

This is perhaps a special case because my application runs within a custom and hosted Electron instance, which has more elevated access than a typical browser, but still behaves as a browser for this kind of resolution of javascript imports.

So, what is needed for a dynamic import of type "node:" to work?  You can't be running it within a browser environment, or at the very least, you can try using various polyfill techniques at build time to try to replace the dynamic import statements (as helpfully provided by AKX above).

This is perhaps obvious in retrospect, but since I couldn't find this answer spelled out so plainly anywhere, I'm leaving it here for future folks.